# Save value to main controller from pop over controller on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to objective-c and need some help setting this up. Basically, there's the main view and it opens a pop over view. the pop over has a segmented control with 2 buttons. clicking btn1 should save 0 to a variable in the main view, and btn2 should save 1. Closing the reopening the popover should display the previously selected value.

```
MainViewController.h
NSInteger data;
MainViewController.m

PopOverViewController.h
PopOverViewController.m
```

Could someone give me some tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no straight forward way to "return" a value from a sub controller, so you can use a simple pointer.

In PopOverViewController, declare an instance variable

```
NSInteger *data;
```

...

```
@property NSInteger * data;
```

And then set the pointer after you alloc the controller

```
popOverController.data = &data;
```

Later btn1 will run

```
*data = 0;
```

etc... This sets the value in the original data variable.

Comment: do i need to retain the property?

Comment: so with this will changing the variable in main controller also change the value of the variable in the popover controller? and vice versa?

Comment: No need to retain it because you aren't using Objective C's memory management.

Comment: Yes, the data is stored in the original variable. The second variable is a pointer, so it "points" to the original variable. There is only one copy of the actual information.